# WP-CLI plugin install causes PHP fatal error - Using $this when not in object context

Tags: wp-cli

When running **sudo wp install plugin pluginname --allowroot**

It causes an error:

*PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/blocks.php:89*

We have a custom plugin that has this line:

```
 class Block{ 
    public static function Run() {           
      add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets',array($this,'RegisterBlock')); //complains on this line
```

When installing via WP admin - it works fine. But when using WP-CLI it fails.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
public static function Run() {
```

The ["static"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) here means this function doesn't have an object context i.e. it's intended to be called as `Block::Run()` without actually making a Block. That said, `$block = new Block(); $block->Run();` will still work, but it still doesn't have $this set inside the method.

Instead you can use the class name instead of $this to make a [callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for a static method:

```php
class Block{ 
    public static function Run() {           
      add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', array('Block', 'RegisterBlock') );
```

But I've no idea how the original code is working in wp-admin. Is it code definitely being called?

Comment: Thank you. If there was a namespace, do I add it before the class name like: 

add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', array('Namespace\Block', 'RegisterBlock') );

Comment: I'm not sure sorry, but that looks sensible yes.